# How to print file path in Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have got a text file where in I store 'file names' along with its path

**Example**

```
Modules\App\a.txt
Modules\Engine\b.txt
```

I am able to get 'filename' using `@echo %%~nxA`.

However, when I try `@echo %%~pA` it prints my **current windows path** and **file path**

**Example**

When I execute the script from D:\Temp it prepends \Temp

```
\Temp\Modules\App\a.txt
\Temp\Modules\Engine\b.txt
```

However, output should be `'Modules\App\a.txt'` and NOT `'\Temp\Modules\App\a.txt'`

In short I am looking out for an windows equivalent of `dirname`

Comment: You posted only fragments of your batch, the for command is missing. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: As above, you've not provided us with sufficient information to enable us to help you with the code. Please provide the batch file code as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52777744/edit), formatted using the `{}` button.

Comment: If you want to use `Modules\App\a.txt` as the text file contains, then use just `%%A`. So what is your problem? Do you want the relative path ``Modules\App\`` without file name and extension? Yes, then your description of the requirement for the task is wrong.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want relative paths. `for` isn't able to provide that, but you can work around it - just remove the current folder path:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(echo Modules\App\a.txt
 echo Modules\Engine\b.txt)>file.txt

for /f "delims=" %%A in (file.txt) do (
  set "tmp=%%~fA"
  REM set "tmp=%%~dpA"
  echo !tmp:%cd%\=!
)
```

Result:

```
Modules\App\a.txt
Modules\Engine\b.txt
```

Comment: The `set` and `echo` command lines can be replaced by `echo %%A` to output exactly the same. Yes, original poster described that `Modules\App\a.txt` is wanted as output, but that does not match with the question in title.

Comment: @Mofi that's true for the whole line, but won't work for `@echo %%~pA`, as mentioned in the question. `set "tmp=%%~dpA"` solves that.

Comment: I suppose that original poster wants ``Modules\App\`` and ``Modules\Engine\`` from the strings in the text file which can be better achieved with `set "RelativePath=%%A"` and `call echo %%RelativePath:\%%~nxA=\%%` without usage of delayed expansion. `%CD%`  usually expands to a path with no backslash at end except the current directory is the root directory of a drive which must be extra taken into account on usage of `%CD%` concatenated with ``\``. My second command line requires that every file name has a relative path in `file.txt` and also does not work for any possible use case.

Comment: @Mofi: yes, there are many ways to skin a cat. As long as you don't know the cat, it's hard to decide which way to choose. There *might*  be a folder in the path with the same name as the file (not very likely though...)